# PowerShell: Window service must stop before proceeding

Tags: powershell, service

I have a PowerShell script where I am stopping a Windows service.  I, then, wish to wait until the service shows a `'Stopped'` status.  I issue the appropriate command to stop the service.  I have tried to use a WHILE loop similar to...

```
While ((Get-Service -Name $ServiceName).Status -ne 'Stopped')
{
     Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

I have also added a counter to the above WHILE loop that checks the counter to see that it is not over a count of 5. The counter works as it exits the WHILE loop but the service still does not show a status of `'Stopped'`.  The service must be stopped before I continue with the remaining code in the script.

Comment: But are you running `Stop-Service` or `.Stop()` for the service you're trying to stop  prior to the code you're showing us and the process still shows as `'Running'`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Is the service stopping and just slow, or does the service fail to stop? Why are you breaking out of the loop if the service must be stopped before moving on? Maybe change to `While (($Service = Get-Service -name $ServiceName).Status -ne 'Stopped')` then inside the loop `If($Service.Status -eq 'Running'){ Stop-Service -Name $ServiceName -Force}`

Comment: To be clear, `Stop-Service` **already** waits for the service to go down before continuing, unless you specify `-NoWait`. The timeout is based on the service itself, but if it needs to be longer, you can override it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871759/7411885

Comment: If `Stop-Service` errors out though, it won't end the script since the error is non-terminating. This can be changed with `Stop-Service MyService -ErrorAction Stop`

Answer (score 0):

Just use WaitForStatus:
[ServiceController.WaitForStatus Method](http://Simply%20use%20WaitForStatus:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)